# Access request parameters in Freemarker templates with JForum

Tags: freemarker

I'm using JForum and I wanted to access request parameters in Freemarker template files.
I googled a bit and tried the followings without any luck.

```
${RequestParameters.paramName}
${RequestParameters['paramName']}
${args['paramName']}
${param.paramName}
```

They all return RequestParameters is undefined or args is undefined sort of errors.

I saw some questions like "How do you access request parameters in Freemarker templates using Spring MVC?" but I could not get help from those questions and answers.

**Followup**

So as far as I've found out, Freemarker does not reveal those information. You need to add those info by yourself.

I got some help from javaranch.com. Here is the link, if it would help anyone who's asking the same question: [Access request parameters in Freemarker templates](http://www.coderanch.com/t/640233/jforum/Access-request-parameters-Freemarker-templates#2938205).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe JForum doesn't expose the request parameters at all. FreeMarker is not like JSP, it's not bound to Servlet-s. The library/framework that embeds FreeMarker decides if it will expose the request (and the session, etc.), and how. Cleaner applications won't do that. It breaks the separation of concerns (and pure MVC).

Comment: If it breaks the separation of concerns, what should I do ? I don't want to turn this application into spaghetti. So, is using parameter information on the view layer, breaking the separation of concerns ? then how do I avoid that ?

Comment: HTTP request parameters are technically details. If you need to display something, then you put it into the FreeMarker data-model, and for the template it doesn't mater where it came from (from a request parameter, from the session, from a database query, etc). Though I don't know what exactly that parameter is for, and if JForum has some plugin mechanism that lets you put that value into the data-model.